# Spark job fails with FileNotFoundException on Yarn after 7 hours

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a job with 4000 executors to process 3 years of data ~ 1 Petabyte. I run one query per day and process 2-3 days at the same time. Approx after processing 700 days total (~ 7 hours) it fails with some shuffle exception.

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10259 in stage 447.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10259.3 in stage 447.0 (TID 1691674, machine0689.datacenter.domain.com, executor 2647): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data4/yarn/nm/usercache/my_application/appcache/application_1535740315164_66119/blockmgr-10614d00-de24-4b2c-8bd6-2463ab4b358c/2e/temp_shuffle_6d6bae3b-d4c4-44e7-b2de-e0cdd71d35e0 (Read-only file system)
```

Has anyone seen this error or help figure it out? Here's the spark configuration:

```
spark.network.timeout=300s
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=60s
spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true

spark.executor.instances=4000
spark.executor.cores=4
spark.executor.memory=32G
spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4G

spark.driver.cores=8
spark.driver.memory=32G
spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4G
```

Full StackTrace:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:547)
at com.mycompany.filter.Filter.process(Filter.scala:143)
at com.mycompany.filter.Filter$$anonfun$filterDataset$1.apply(Filter.scala:60)
at com.mycompany.filter.Filter$$anonfun$filterDataset$1.apply(Filter.scala:60)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.internal(Tasks.scala:169)
at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.internal(Tasks.scala:443)
at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:149)
at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10259 in stage 447.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10259.3 in stage 447.0 (TID 1691674, machine0689.datacenter.domain.com, executor 2647): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data4/yarn/nm/usercache/my_application/appcache/application_1535740315164_66119/blockmgr-10614d00-de24-4b2c-8bd6-2463ab4b358c/2e/temp_shuffle_6d6bae3b-d4c4-44e7-b2de-e0cdd71d35e0 (Read-only file system)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

The driver stacktrace looks like:

```
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data4/yarn/nm/usercache/my_application/appcache/application_1535740315164_66119/blockmgr-10614d00-de24-4b2c-8bd6-2463ab4b358c/2e/temp_shuffle_6d6bae3b-d4c4-44e7-b2de-e0cdd71d35e0 (Read-only file system)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: is this on GCP ?

Comment: nope, internal datacenter

Comment: it shows (Read-only file system), when the app opened the path trying to write shuffle data. you should probably point your local dir and log dir to some other location if its an access issue

Comment: That's a good catch. I am not sure how to go around/debug this though, why would the local datanode have read only restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Supply below 2 properties to spark-submit-

```
spark.yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs=<fs path>
Spark.locak.dir=<fs path>
```

Read [Spark WIKI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#important-notes) for more details about these properties.

Comment: how would this help in alleviating this issue?

Comment: I had faced the same issue when I wasn't using local dir properties. In my case, my organization has the retention policy to free-up space from yarn default tmp directory data older than X time. It’s just a precaution for long-running spark jobs to set local dir properly against losing intermediate cache data.